# joomla's hwdvideoshare module help

Tags: php, joomla

i using hwdvideoshare module in joomla and i can't use the Method 1 for Direct Video Conversions. it requires the following things to be done:

```
*  The exec() function need to be enabled in PHP.
* safe_mode must be set to Off. You can check that at Joomla Help -> System Info -> PHP Information)
* php-cli (Command Line Interface to PHP) must be installed in the server and its path set in Server Settings
* safe_mode must be set to Off for php-cli. You can check that executing php -i | grep safe_mode from the command line
```

i've checked the first two settings. i don't know whether php-cli is enabled or not..i'm using php5..how do i enable it, without messing with other php packages?

Answer (score 0):

Are you on a shared webhost?   Most don't have the configuration you need for video conversions.  hwdVideoShare lists the hosts that work with this component.  I used Imageleet and they are very good and not expensive, and are 100% compatible with both Joomla and hwdVideoShare.  Their support desk is also very responsive to any tickets I submit.